# What are these hidden lines tangent to the circle?

Tags: solidworks, technical-drawing, autocad

I don't understand what the hidden lines are nor the fillets tangent to the center line of the circles if someone can help with the 3d isometric that would help a lot. [image: I]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a stiffener that goes around the cylinder that runs across the walls

[image]

**Section View**

[image]

**FUll isometric view**

Comment: Ok thanks a lot , I have another question will this be treated as a rib or not because in my course when there is a rib we don't hatch it in sectional views , so should I hatch this or not ?